# Mobiscroll ParseInt exception on Samsung Galaxy S3

Tags: javascript, android, html, mobiscroll

After clicking the input field that opens the DateTimePicker (we use [this one from mobiscroll](http://demo.mobiscroll.com/datetime#theme=default&language=de)) our Android HTML5 App crashes with a  NumberFormatException at parseInt (which is trying to parse "11.07.1993"). Obviously it should not be parsing the date. Strangely enough, this Bug only happens on Samsung Galaxy S3.

The code that calls the mobiscroller looks like this:

```
$(function () 
{
    // create a datepicker                  
    $("#ti_gebdat").mobiscroll().date(
    {
        display: 'bottom', 
        dateFormat: 'dd.mm.yy', 
        dateOrder: 'ddmmyy', 
        lang: 'de', 
        onBeforeShow: function (html, inst) 
        {
            inst.setDate(dataclass.gebDat, true, 2);
        }
    }); 
    $("#ti_gebdat").bind('change', function (event) 
    {
        var dt = $.mobiscroll.parseDate('yy-mm-dd',event.target.value,'');                      
        event.target.value = $.mobiscroll.formatDate('dd.mm.yy', dt, '');
        dataclass.setGebDat(dt);
    });                 
    $('#ti_gebdat').scroller('option', {  maxDate: new Date() });
});
```

The input field looks like this:

```
<input name="ti_gebdat" id="ti_gebdat" style="text-align: right"
     placeholder="" value="" type="date" readonly>
```

How can I make it work on Galaxy S3 too?

**UPDATE**

Also crashes with Galaxy S4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that **Samsung Galaxy S3** and **S4** do actually support the element `input` with `type="date"` and calls its own DatePicker. Since the mobiscroll DatePicker was called too at the same time, it resulted in a crash. Removing `date` from the `input` element would solve the problem.

Comment: well, since nobody else answered ;)